# Select query unable to retrieve result

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-convert

I have a query which on executing, gives the below error.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string.

The Query is

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_NUMBER 
FROM PER_PERSON 
WHERE IS_ACTIVE = 'Y' 
AND '31-01-2022 00:00:00' 
BETWEEN EFF_START_DATE and ISNULL(EFF_END_DATE, '31-01-2022 00:00:00')  
AND ANALYST = (SELECT USERNAME FROM SEC_USER WHERE USER_ID = '100061')
```

Attaching screenshot for reference.

[image: Screenshotsql]

TIA

Comment: Try to use a more "standard" (*sane*?) date format like `'2022-01-31 00:00:00'` for your date literal or explicitly `convert()` the string with the right format designation.

Comment: @stickybit, thanks for the insight